# Storybook: how can I pass a global setting to story's / component's argument

Tags: storybook

I'm using Storybook (6.5) with Twig templates (`@storybook/html` with `twig` and `twigjs-loader` packages).

I'm going to simplify my use case, but basically I need to:

1. Add a global switch to the toolbar (a dropdown with 2 options, 'type a' / 'type b')
2. Depending on which type is selected, a relevant class needs to be added to each component's wrapper (type-a / type-b)
3. I need to pass selected type to component's Twig template

I've managed to implement 1 and 2. Here's what I've got so far (works fine):

```js
// .preview.js

[...]

export const globalTypes = {
  typeSelector: {
    title: "Type",
    defaultValue: "a",
    toolbar: {
      dynamicTitle: true,
      items: [{value: "a", title: "Type A"},{value: "b", title: "Type B"}]
    }
  }
}

export const decorators = [
  (storyFn, context) =>
      `<div class="type-${context.globals.typeSelector}">${storyFn()}</div>`,
];
```

Unfortunately I'm struggling to implement the last point.

Let's say I've got a component with the following template:

```
// MyComponent.twig

<div class="my-component">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  {% if type === "a" %}
    <p>Some text specific to type a</p>
  {% endif %}
  <p>This text is always displayed regardless of type</p>
</div>
```

In `MyComponent.stories.js` file I want to be able to access the value of that globally selected type and pass it to the Twig template as an argument.

```js
// MyComponent.stories.js

import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.twig";

export default {
  title: "Components/My Component",
  // Can I access globally selected type and pass it here to every component in this story?         
  args: {
    type: [TYPE SELECTED VIA TOOLBAR]
  }
};

export const Default = (args) => MyComponent(args);

Default.args = {
  title: "Some title defined on component level"
}
```

When I was searching for the answer I found this article: https://www.bekk.christmas/post/2021/3/storybook-background-change-on-prop-change, which does the opposite: passes story's argument to a global parameter, and updates it accordingly. I tried something similar (rather than listening to story updates and updating globals I was trying to listen to global updates and update 'type' argument in stories), but I got stuck. This is how far I got:

```js
// preview.js

import { addons } from "@storybook/addons";
import { GLOBALS_UPDATED, UPDATE_STORY_ARGS } from "@storybook/core-events";

let channel = addons.getChannel();

const typeListener = (globals) => {
  const selectedType = globals.globals.typeSelector;
  // This works - typeListener function runs every time globals are updated and logs selected type value.
  console.log(selectedType);
  if (selectedType) {
    // Now I need to find all stories with 'type' attribute, and set it to selectedType.
    ??
    channel.emit(UPDATE_STORY_ARGS, {
      ???
    });
  }
};

function setupTypeListener() {
  channel.removeListener(GLOBALS_UPDATED, typeListener);
  channel.addListener(GLOBALS_UPDATED, typeListener);
}

setupTypeListener();
```

Is this even the way to go about it? Or is there an easier way to do it? Any help would be much appreciated!